# Migration module that is located in subdirectory

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am migrating an Angular app to NativeScript using a code-sharing structure.

To migrate the Angular modules, I am using:

```
ng g migrate-module --name=nameModule
```

But this command assumes that the module is under the folder /app, and to have the project better organised I have the modules in a folder app/modules.

Is there a way to indicate the path of the module? I have tried:

```
ng g migrate-module --name=modules/nameModule
```

But is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In the cases of modules with non-standard file names, you can provide a full path to the module by using the --module-path paramet*

**Example:**

```
ng g migrate-module --name=nameModule --module-path=modules/myModule-md.ts
```

ref:
https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-sharing/migrating-a-web-project

Comment: Thanks, it works. I don't know how I missed it when I was reading the docs!

Comment: @AlexBean great! (:

Answer (score 1):

This is what the actual command looks like.  My module is located at

```
src/app/features/scheduler/scheduler.module.ts

ng g migrate-module --name=scheduler --module-path=features/scheduler/scheduler.module.ts
```